# How to display sold product qty in list.phtml

Tags: magento2

I use module to display sold product qty on product page.

Here is code from custom module .phtml file

```
<?php
/**
 * Solwin Infotech
 * Solwin Most View Sold Extension
 *
 * @category   Solwin
 * @package    Solwin_MostViewSold
 * @copyright  Copyright © 2006-2020 Solwin (https://www.solwininfotech.com)
 * @license    https://www.solwininfotech.com/magento-extension-license/
 */
?>
<?php
$enabled = $viewenabled = $soldenabled = '';
$helper = $this->helper('Solwin\MostViewSold\Helper\Data');
$enabled = $helper->getConfigValue('most_viewed_section/most_viewed_group/active');
$viewenabled = $helper->getConfigValue('most_viewed_section/most_viewed_group/most_viewed_enable');
$soldenabled = $helper->getConfigValue('most_viewed_section/most_viewed_group/most_sold_enable');

$viewed_btn_label = $helper->getConfigValue('most_viewed_section/most_viewed_group/viewed_btn_label');
$sold_btn_label = $helper->getConfigValue('most_viewed_section/most_viewed_group/sold_btn_label');

if ($enabled) {
    $soldcount = $viewedcount = 0;
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $pid = $_product->getEntityId();
    $producttypeid = $_product->getTypeId();
    ?>
    <div class="mostviewed-sold">
        <?php
        /*
         * Get counts for most viewed
         */
        if ($viewenabled) {
            $viewedcount = $helper->getMostViewCount($pid);
            ?>
            <div class="mostviewd">
                <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($viewed_btn_label.':')) ?></label>
                <span class="solwin_count" data-count=<?= /* @noEscape */ (int) $viewedcount ?>>0</span>
            </div>

        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        /*
         * Get sold quantity
         */
        if ($soldenabled) {
            $soldcount = $helper->getMostSoldCount($pid, $producttypeid);
            ?>
            <div class="mostsold">
                <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($sold_btn_label.':')) ?></label>
                <span class="solwin_count" data-count=<?= /* @noEscape */ (int) $soldcount ?>>0</span>
            </div>
        <?php }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
} ?>

<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.solwin_count').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).data('count')
            }, {
                duration: 4000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function (now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Which code should I copy to display also sold product qty under product name on list.phtml?

I have tried in several ways but I get an error every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is responsible for rendering sold product count on Product page, you need to modify it a bit to use it on listing page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Solwin Infotech
 * Solwin Most View Sold Extension
 *
 * @category   Solwin
 * @package    Solwin_MostViewSold
 * @copyright  Copyright © 2006-2020 Solwin (https://www.solwininfotech.com)
 * @license    https://www.solwininfotech.com/magento-extension-license/
 */
?>
<?php
$enabled = $viewenabled = $soldenabled = '';
$helper = $this->helper('Solwin\MostViewSold\Helper\Data');
$enabled = $helper->getConfigValue('most_viewed_section/most_viewed_group/active');
$soldenabled = $helper->getConfigValue('most_viewed_section/most_viewed_group/most_sold_enable');

$sold_btn_label = $helper->getConfigValue('most_viewed_section/most_viewed_group/sold_btn_label');

if ($enabled) {
    $soldcount = 0;
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $pid = $_product->getEntityId();
    $producttypeid = $_product->getTypeId();
    ?>
    <div class="mostviewed-sold">
        <?php
        /*
         * Get sold quantity
         */
        if ($soldenabled) {
            $soldcount = $helper->getMostSoldCount($pid, $producttypeid);
            ?>
            <div class="mostsold">
                <label><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($sold_btn_label.':')) ?></label>
                <span class="solwin_count" data-count=<?= /* @noEscape */ (int) $soldcount ?>>0</span>
            </div>
        <?php }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
} ?>

<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.solwin_count').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).data('count')
            }, {
                duration: 4000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function (now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

You need to remove or replace this code as in list.phtml product object can be used from foreach loop `$_product = $block->getProduct();`

Hope this will help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in Block and add below code in that.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class SoldItems extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  protected $_soldCollection
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection $soldCollection,
     array $data = []) {
     $this->_soldCollection = $soldCollection;
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }
 /*
   returns sold qty by using sku
 */
  public function getSoldQty($sku){
     $soldProduct = $this->_soldCollection->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 
     $sku)->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')->getFirstItem(); 
     $soldQty = $soldProduct ->getOrderedQty();
     return $soldQty;
  }
}
```

The above function returns the sold Qty by taking sku as parameter.

call this block function in your list.phtml by passing sku of the product as a parameter.

Hope this may help you!!